# Resharper 4.5 has broken my colour scheme

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper, themes, colors

I'm not sure exactly what went wrong here, but ReSharper 4.5 RTM seems to have stolen my Visual Studio colour theme. I normally use [Fredrik Kalseth's wicked theme](http://www.frickinsweet.com/tools/Theme.mvc.aspx), and I've been using ReSharper since version 2.0. Never before has this happened - not even while using the 4.5 Beta. My scheme remained intact without detrimental interference - well, actually ReSharper did its normal highlighting which was actually quite complimentary! But this time, when building my new machine, the outcome looks like this:

[image: Dark colours meant for a light theme]

Yes I know that ReShaper colours can be configured under Tools->Font and Colors, but firstly, I don't want to have to do that, and secondly, I want to understand why this has happened only now, and never before.

When I uninstall ReSharper, the colours go back to normal. I have tried removing the theme and resharper and reinstalling in different orders to no avail. I apply the theme with a code file open, and see a brief flash of the correct colours how they used to look, and then ReSharper takes over.

I've tried [Ryan and Joel's AWESOME theme generator](http://www.frickinsweet.com/tools/Theme.mvc.aspx), but I see the same brief flash of the correct colours being applied after importing, and then the crappy colours overlay themselves again. I say they are crappy only in the context of a dark theme, on a light theme they look just fine.

I just want to know how to have my cake and eat it like it's been all this time. I must stress, that the theme and resharper have been working hand in hand perfectly together all the time I've used it (6 months at least), it's only happened on my new machine - my old machine looks and works fine. Oh - and I have a fully licensed version of ReSharper - not a trial.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open Visual Studio
Go to Resharper > Options... > Code Inspection > Settings

Untick "Color identifiers".
Press ok.

Comment: Many thanks...you're a .. erm...Saint! Worked like a charm - not sure when/if I ticked that box, but it looks much better now.

Comment: It's true that this will fix the issue, but it also turns off a very useful feature of ReSharper.  The issue here is that most colour schemes out there don't take advantage of the additional colourings that R# adds to VS.  I took the time to choose colours for each of these in the Options->FontsAndColours section and am very pleased with the results.

Answer (score 2):

Try going into Tools -> Fonts and Colors, change nothing and click ok. It's sorted out problems like this for some people I know. I think it makes VS reapply the stored color settings.